# What is New Folder@IHTD

Tags: nautilus, directory

I use Ubuntu 21.10 64 bit with Gnome 40.4.0 and Wayland. On the Desktop, if I right click, then on  => New folder, I get a small window with New Folder@IHTD and an empty box to name the new folder I am about to create. What does IHTD mean?
If I create a new folder via Nautilus, there is no mention of IHTD.
In both cases, the result seems to be the same...